# Google Chrome iframe content prints in large text

Tags: php, google-chrome, printing

I am using a hidden iframe to print page contents generated by php, this works fine in Firefox and until this weekend it has also been working fine in Chrome, now in Chrome it prints in a lot larger text than the html is set to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=135563

It's a bug that just occurred in the latest version of Webkit which was released with Google Chrome version 20, has to deal with the css being messed up specifically when printing an iframe. Unfortunately the only thing you can do in the time being is to print directly from viewing the page (iframe printing won't work, so you can't load a page to be printed), or have your users switch to Firefox.

Hopefully this saves you the many hours I spent looking into the issue yesterday!

Comment: Thanks for the advice, should have come straight here, as i also spent hours trying to figure it out!!